# What is the upgrade manager?

Tags: apt, upgrade, update-manager, software-updater

What exactly is the role of the upgrade manager?
I've noticed that the last few releases of ubuntu downloads an upgrade manager once you press the upgrade button. I thought the upgrade was merely handled by apt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade manager is a Graphical User Interface (GUI) to the APT system. It uses `update-manager-core` as back end which at the same time uses `python-apt`. So at the end you will be still using the apt-get libraries to get the work done.

The Upgrade Manager instead of the usual `sudo apt-get upgrade` uses a tactic similar to `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` which normally removes/installs more packages than what `upgrade` does. So, yeah, behind the curtains you are still using `apt` just that with a nice GUI that doesn't looks as scary as the command line.

Answer (score 1):

It is still handled by apt. All the Graphic Software install programs in Ubuntu do invoke apt in the background and provide buttons and a nice looking gui. But it's nearly the same as when you type `apt-get install <package-name>` in a terminal.

Comment: So the upgrade manager that it installs is just the GUI?

Comment: Yes, everything that installs software in ubuntu belongs to apt, except building software from source code. An upgrade would be `apt-get upgrade` in terminal, but ubuntu has also another method (see: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html#do-release-upgrade) `do-release-upgrade`, but this tool does also specicifc system configuration changes and calls apt, just like any graphical program.